# SQL Server Query for account statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I generate last three transactions from the below table?

```
Date        Tran        dr  cr  total
-------------------------------------
2017-04-13                  
2017-07-15 
2017-07-15 
2017-10-17 
2017-10-17 abc              10  10
2017-11-12 def              10  20 
2017-11-12 ghi          5       15
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: What do you mean here by "generate?"  If you can see this output then you presumably already have a way to generate this.

Comment: provide more details, where these values came from?

Comment: I need a query for displaying last three records, above table are virtually created, i cannot use (select top 3 * from Table_name order by Date Desc) or something like that.

Comment: **`Generate`** from where? Provide sample table data and the code which you have tried so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if your requirement is to get the 3 transactions with the latest date. you can use either of the following.

**Simple Order by :**

```
select
top 3 
* from YourTable
where isnull(Tran,'')<>''
order by [Date] desc
```

**using Row Number**

```
;with cte
as
(
  select
   seqno = row_number() over(order by [date] desc),
  *
  from YourTable
where isnull(Tran,'')<>''
 )
 select
 * from cte
 where SeqNo <=3
order by SeqNo desc
```

Comment: select
top 3 
* from YourTable
order by [Date] desc This code will display my result in descending order . I need my result like   


2017-10-17 abc              10  10
2017-11-12 def              10  20 
2017-11-12 ghi          5       15

Comment: try the second solution

Answer (score 0):

Like this you should your expected result:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT TOP 3 *
   FROM TransactionTable
   ORDER BY [Date] DESC
) AS t
ORDER by t.[Date]
```